# Detail disclosure button in indexed UITableView allowed by HIG?

Tags: iphone, ios5

Is it allowed(as per Apple HIG) to show Detail Disclosure button in an Indexed UITableView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can use the detail disclosure accessory type on both `UITableView` styles.

Also remember the HIG is just guidelines. Do what you want - Apple are not *that* scary!

**Update:**

As @jrturton points out, you're talking about a table view with an index on the right - like an alphabet selection. I'd say it's still OK with that and it can be done, but be careful that it doesn't become hard for the user to both use the index and tap the detail disclosure buttons.

Comment: Yes, the HIG is just a set of guidelines, but most of the time when people violate the HIG, it makes their app worse, not better.

Comment: He's not talking about table styles, he's talking about table views with an index on the side - so a detail disclosure button would be right next to the index bar, and you run the risk of mistaken touches.

Comment: Sure, of course. But that's a totally different question. Asking if it's "allowed" indicates to me that @Naresh wanted to know if Apple would reject based on it.

Comment: @jrtuton - Very good point. I appear to have totally glossed over that when I first wrote it. Thanks for pointing out.